# How can I limit a user to check only 3 Checkboxes in a Gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, checkbox, code-behind

I have a gridview with a bunch of rows, the first column contains checkboxes in an item template.  I want the user to only select 3 different checkboxes max.  If they select a fourth checkbox the selection will be denied/undone/etc.  I'd like to pop up a message telling them about the restriction if they try to check a 4th checkbox.

Here's my grid:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv_pain" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="ds_grid_pain"  ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" style="text-align: left; font-size: x-small; ">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPain" runat="server" onclick="CheckCheckBoxes()" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DrugID" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="DrugID">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DrugID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_DrugID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DrugID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="NickName" HeaderText="NickName" SortExpression="NickName" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="DrugName" HeaderText="DrugName" SortExpression="DrugName" ItemStyle-Width="500px">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quan1" HeaderText="Quan1" SortExpression="Quan1">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Quan2" HeaderText="Quan2" SortExpression="Quan2">
                            <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                            </asp:BoundField>
                        </Columns>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                    </asp:GridView>
```

Here's the javascript I've tried to add, but it's not doing anything new.  I also added `onclick="CheckCheckBoxes()"`  to the item template field in the gridview.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkCheckedCount(objChk) {
        var objHf = document.getElementById('<%=hfChkCount.ClientID %>')
        if (objChk.checked == true) {
            if (objHf.value >= 5) {
                alert('You cannot select more than 5 items.');
                objChk.checked = false;
            }
            else { objHf.value = parseInt(objHf.value) + 1; }
        }
        else { objHf.value = parseInt(objHf.value) - 1; }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: WIth jquery you can [limit checkboxes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001844/how-to-limit-the-number-of-selected-checkboxes) and [change labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833982/change-label-when-checkbox-is-checked).

Comment: I saw that post... but my check boxes are asp:CheckBox.  I couldn't get that to work.  Thoughts?

Comment: It could be that your checkbox id's are getting changed by ASP.net. This link explains a workaround. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733771/check-asp-net-checkbox-with-jquery

Comment: Are you suggesting that I add javascript with the ClientID in there?  I've tried that, and just edited my post to reflect what I've tried...